# Syntax highlight SQL queries when using non-standard SQL packages in Goland IDE

Tags: sql, go, goland

When using Goland it is very useful to get SQL syntax highlight and autocompletion based on my connected datasources.  Unfortunately this only seems to work when I'm using the standard Go sql package and does not work when I use custom packages that effectively wrap the sql package calls.  I was wondering if it's possible to tell Goland that specific functions / parameters are actually SQL queries / SQL statements.

Here's an example of Goland allowing SQL completion for methods on sql.DB struct vs not allowing completion on custom query.ReadOnlyDB struct:

[image: Works for sql.DB does not work for custom query.ReadOnlyDB]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, you can specify `//language=SQL` comment before the statement:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    //language=SQL
    str := "SELECT USERNAME FROM EXAMPLE"
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

There are a few tickets to improve SQL highlighting in GoLand and you can follow them:

- [GO-10398](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-10398). SQL highlighting for custom packages/proxies.
- [GO-10011](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-10011). Inject SQL automatically to strings that start with SQL queries (SELECT, CREATE, DELETE, and so on).

Comment: This isn't just for SQL or GoLand. It's a wider feature in JetBrains IDEs known as "language injections". See this link for more details: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/using-language-injections.html#use-language-injection-comments